# what can be the most efficient way to find the vertices within a certian radius on the mesh?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make a sculpting application using three js. I was able to manipulate the geometry one vertex at a time. Now I want to push or pull a group of vertices within the brush radius from the point of intersection. for this purpose, how can I find the nearest vertices to the point of intersection on the mesh without brute force calculating the distance of each vertex from the intersection point because the mesh can be very high resolution